# Opening Div at a specific position

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a div at a specific location on the page. When I focus on a textbox the div should be opened(made visible). I am able to do this part. The problem is it opens right underneath the textbox and when there is no scroll on the page, it creates one. I need help in showing the div above the textbox when there is more space on upper half of the page then the lower half of the page. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36vdoaqo/2/) I have created and if someone can edit it, it would be of too much help to me.

And this is how I am opening the div:

```
function openDIV(activatorCtl) {

            var leftpos = 0;
            var toppos = 0;
            var sScrollTop = getScrollTop;
            var aTag = activatorCtl;
            do {
                aTag = aTag.offsetParent;
                sScrollTop = (aTag.scrollTop > sScrollTop) ? aTag.scrollTop : sScrollTop;
                leftpos += aTag.offsetLeft;
                toppos += aTag.offsetTop;
            } while (aTag.tagName != 'BODY');

            document.getElementById("divDetails").style.left = leftpos + "px";
            document.getElementById("divDetails").style.top = toppos + 20 + "px";
            document.getElementById("divDetails").style.zIndex = "999";
            document.getElementById("divDetails").style.visibility = "visible";

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/36vdoaqo/3/

I added an if for when the toppos is bigger than 250 (your divs height)

```
if(toppos <= 250)
```

Another tip:

You use this 4 times in a row:

```
document.getElementById("divDetails")
```

save this element in an variable to get shorter statements like:

```
var detailsDiv = document.getElementById("divDetails");
detailsDiv.style.left = leftpos + "px";
detailsDiv.style.zIndex = "999";
```

EDIT: i did not save the jsfiddle properly.

Comment: There isn't any change in the behavior.